# MultiValueDictKeyError at /count/ while using .GET[]

Tags: python, django

I am getting the below-mentioned error while executing the code:-

> MultiValueDictKeyError at /count/ 'textbox' Request Method:   GET
>   Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/count/ Django Version:    2.1
>   Exception Type:   MultiValueDictKeyError Exception Value:  'textbox'
>   Exception
>   Location: /Users/rajans/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py
>   in **getitem**, line 79 Python
>   Executable:   /Users/rajans/anaconda3/bin/python Python Version:  3.7.0
>   Python Path:   ['/Users/rajans/Documents/djangoprojects/wordcount', 
>   '/Users/rajans/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip', 
>   '/Users/rajans/anaconda3/lib/python3.7', 
>   '/Users/rajans/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', 
>   '/Users/rajans/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages', 
>   '/Users/rajans/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aeosa'] Server
>   time: Tue, 5 Feb 2019 06:39:06 +0000

Python

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def homepage(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')


def contact(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h2> This is a contact_us page</h2><br> You can write to rajan.sharma@freshworks.com for any query")

def count(request):
    data=request.GET['textbox']
    data_list=split(data)
    data_len=len(data_list)
    return render(request,'count.html',{'length':data_len})
--------
```

### html form:-

```
<h1>Word Count</h1><br>
This is the home page for the Word count.

<form action="{% url 'count' name%}">  <!--  "{% url 'count' %}". this will load the url even if the path is changed..it will look for the name count-->
    <textarea name="textbox" cols=40 rows="10"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="count"/>

</form>
```

count.html

```
<h1>Counted</h1><br/>
The length is :- {{length}}
```

Comment: try `data=request.GET.get('textbox')`

Comment: why dont u getting error split is not defined? That is not right way to split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using http://127.0.0.1:8000/count/ this url when ever this url call to function it will go with GET method in your function you are trying to access a "textbox" but in first time visit textbox parameter is not there so it is showing error

you need to modify your view function and write one condition

```
def count(request):
    data=request.GET.get('textbox', None)
    if data:
        data_list=split(data)
        data_len=len(data_list)
        return render(request,'count.html',{'length':data_len})
    else:
        return render(request,'add here your html page name where input form is there')
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're not passing textbook variable as parameter in URL.

Try calling your URL as /count_url/?textbook="value that you want to pass"

Also, would suggest to use .get method as

```
data = request.GET.get('textbook', None)

if data:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the MultiValueDict's get method, you can also provide default value if `textbox` not present.

```
data=request.GET.get('textbox', None)
if data:
   #process
else:
   #process
```

Comment: now its giving this error:- 

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

new code:-

```
def count(request):
 data=request.GET.get('textbox',None)
 print (data)
 data_list = data.split()
 data_len = len(data_list)
 print(data_len)
 return render(request,'count.html')
```

Comment: This error show that you are getting None in `data` make sure you are passing some value in `textbox` or you need to handle in code for `None` values

Comment: Can you post the URL which you're hitting?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here, first, you have to deal with the fact that (as the other answer states already) you might reach this view without a `textbox` key in your `GET`.

That you can fix as shown in the others answers:

```
data=request.GET.get('textbox', None)
```

But the one I'd worry about is the `action` attribute of your form:

```
<form action="{% url 'count' name%}">
```

with that, you're saying your `count` view receives another parameter, but that's not what we see in your view implementation:

```
def count(request):
    ...
```

So you should change your view to:

```
def count(request, name):
    data=request.GET.get('textbox', None)
    data_len = 0
    if data:
        data_list=split(data)
        data_len=len(data_list)
    return render(request,'count.html',{'length':data_len})
```

And your URL should also specify your view can receive another param:

```
re_path(r'count/(\w+)?', count, name=count)
```